# KMM(Kotlin Multiplatform) compileKotlinIosArm64 error

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, multiplatform

**Errors occur in modules when building a project on Mac Ventura.**

**Errors**

:common:base_swift:compileKotlinIosArm64

:common:base_swift:compileKotlinIosX64

Could not find "org.jetbrains.compose.runtime:runtime-saveable" in [/Users/alehandro/StudioProjects/test, /Users/alehandro/.konan/klib, /Users/alehandro/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-x86_64-1.8.10/klib/common, /Users/alehandro/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-x86_64-1.8.10/klib/platform/ios_arm64]

***Dependencies***

```
object Dependencies {
 
    object Android {
        private const val version = "7.3.1"
        const val gradlePlugin = "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$version"
        const val composeActivity = "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1"
 
        object Compose {
            private const val version = "1.4.2"
            const val runtime = "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$version"
            const val ui = "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$version"
            const val material = "androidx.compose.material:material:$version"
            const val tooling = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$version"
            const val icons = "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$version"
        }
    }
 
    object Kodein {
        const val core = "org.kodein.di:kodein-di:7.1.0"
    }
 
    object Kotlin {
       private const val version = "1.8.10"
        const val gradlePlugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$version"
 
        object Serialization {
            const val gradlePlugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.6.21"
            const val serialization = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.0"
        }
 
 
        object Coroutines {
            private const val version = "1.7.0"
            const val core = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$version"
        }
    }
 
    object SqlDelight {
        private const val version = "1.5.3"
 
        const val gradlePlugin = "com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:$version"
        const val core = "com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$version"
        const val android = "com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$version"
        const val ios = "com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$version"
    }
 
    object Compose {
        private const val version = "1.2.0-beta01"
        const val gradlePlugin = "org.jetbrains.compose:compose-gradle-plugin:$version"
        const val saveable = "org.jetbrains.compose.runtime:runtime-saveable:$version"
    }
 
    object Ktor {
        private const val version = "2.3.0"
        const val core = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$version"
        const val json = "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$version"
        const val ios = "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$version"
        const val negotiation = "io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$version"
        const val kotlin_json = "io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$version"
        const val serialization = "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$version"
        const val logging = "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$version"
        const val android = "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$version"
        const val okhttp = "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$version"
    }
 
    object Library {
        private const val version = "0.14"
        private const val versionVoyager = "1.0.0-rc05"
 
        object Navigation {
            const val navigator = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:$versionVoyager"
            const val bottom = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-bottom-sheet-navigator:$versionVoyager"
            const val tab = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-tab-navigator:$versionVoyager"
            const val transitions = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-transitions:$versionVoyager"}
        object ViewModel {
            const val precompose = "com.adeo:kviewmodel:$version"
        }
        object Molecule {
            const val precompose = "com.adeo:kviewmodel-compose:$version"
        }
 
    }
}

*module base_swift*




plugins {
    id("multiplatform-setup")
    id("android-setup")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
}
 
version = "0.0.1"
 
kotlin {
 
    cocoapods {
        summary = "/* project name */ iOS SDK"
        homepage = "https://google.com"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
 
        framework {
            transitiveExport = false
            baseName = "SharedSDK"
            export(project(":common:core"))
            export(project(":common:core_utils"))
            export(project(":common:verification:domain"))
            export(project(":common:verification:presentation"))
            export(project(":common:authorization:domain"))
            export(project(":common:authorization:presentation"))
            export(project(":common:umbrella_core"))
        }
    }
    ios()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project(":common:core"))
                implementation(project(":common:core_utils"))
                implementation(project(":common:umbrella_core"))
                implementation(project(":common:verification:domain"))
                implementation(project(":common:authorization:domain"))
                implementation(project(":common:verification:presentation"))
                implementation(project(":common:authorization:presentation"))
            }
        }
 
        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                api(project(":common:core"))
                api(project(":common:core_utils"))
                api(project(":common:umbrella_core"))
                api(project(":common:verification:domain"))
                api(project(":common:authorization:domain"))
                api(project(":common:verification:presentation"))
                api(project(":common:authorization:presentation"))
            }
        }
    }
}

***module core***





plugins {
    id("multiplatform-setup")
    id("android-setup")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
}
 
kotlin {
    ios()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                api(Dependencies.Kotlin.Serialization.serialization)
                api(Dependencies.Kotlin.Coroutines.core)
 
                api(Dependencies.Ktor.core)
                implementation(Dependencies.Ktor.json)
                implementation(Dependencies.Ktor.serialization)
                implementation(Dependencies.Ktor.negotiation)
                implementation(Dependencies.Ktor.kotlin_json)
                implementation(Dependencies.Ktor.logging)
 
                api(Dependencies.Kodein.core)
 
                api(Dependencies.SqlDelight.core)
            }
        }
        androidMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Dependencies.Ktor.android)
                implementation(Dependencies.SqlDelight.android)
            }
        }
        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Dependencies.Ktor.ios)
                implementation(Dependencies.SqlDelight.ios)
            }
        }
    }
}

***umbrella_core***



plugins {
    id("multiplatform-setup")
    id("android-setup")
}
 
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project(":common:core"))
 
                implementation(project(":common:verification:data"))
 
                implementation(Dependencies.Kodein.core)
            }
        }
    }
}


multiplatform-setup.gradle
 
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("kapt")
}
 
kotlin {
    android()
    ios()
 
    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
 
buildSrc build.gradle
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
 
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    maven(url = "https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}
 
 
dependencies {
    implementation(Dependencies.Kotlin.gradlePlugin)
    implementation(Dependencies.Compose.gradlePlugin)
    implementation(Dependencies.Compose.saveable)
    implementation(Dependencies.Android.gradlePlugin)
    implementation(Dependencies.Kotlin.Serialization.gradlePlugin)
    implementation(Dependencies.SqlDelight.gradlePlugin)
}
 
kotlin {
    sourceSets.getByName("main").kotlin.srcDir("buildSrc/src/main/kotlin")
}
```

mac os on a virtual machine VMware, maybe this will help to identify the error.

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/2046